# Form disappears on submission Shopping cart

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

So at the moment I am trying to create a shopping cart using PHP
currently I'm having trouble submitting a form which adds a product to cart. So essentially I have linked up my database to the my shop.php page, so it loops through each item in the DB and displays the product. Each product has a form which uses POST which when submitted, adds the item to the cart SESSION.

So at the moment, when I click the 'add to cart' button the item is added and works fine. But when i click 'add to cart' for the same item again, the entire product gallery stops working. The issue only occurs when I try to add an item that's already been added. I feel like the issue revolves around submitting the same form twice but I am not quite sure.

```
<div class="container">'
    <div class="box">'
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM items";
        $result_set = mysqli_query($link, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result_set) > 0){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set)){
  ?>
  <div class="displayCase"><br><br><br>
      <form method="POST" action="shop.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
          <img class="phone1" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['image'] )?>" />
          <h1> <?php echo $row['name']  ?> </h1>
          <h2> <?php echo "$" . $row['price'] ?> </h2>
          <label id="QTY">QTY </label><input class="quantity" id="id_form-0-quantity" min="0" name="form-0-quantity" value="1" type="number"><br />
          <select class="phoneType">
              <option value="X">Select Device</option>
              <option value="X">iPhone X/XS</option>
              <option value="X">iPhone X/XS Max</option>
              <option value="X">iPhone 11</option>
              <option value="X">iPhone 11 Pro</option>
              <option value="X">iPhone 11 Pro Max</option>
          </select><br />
          <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name'] ?> ">
          <button type="submit" name="add" value="addToCart">Add To Cart</button>
      </form>
  </div>
        <?php
      }
    }
    ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Cheers

EDIT:
Okay so for some reason it seems to take a full reload after the form is submitted for it to work. So I tried this and it seemed to fix it. Still unsure why this is the case, and whether this is a clean way or if there is a better way of doing it

```
  if (isset($_POST['name'])){
  header("Loction: redirect.php");
}
```

then I created a redirect.php page redirects back to shop.php

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! It looks like your post is mostly code. Please [edit] the question to add in more details.

Comment: Hey, thank you , excited to be here :). I've added more details on to what the issue, if there's anything else that's need please let me know.

Comment: _"But when i click 'add to cart' for the same item again, the entire product gallery stops working."_ What does this mean? Are there any error messages?

Comment: When I click add to cart the first time, the item is added, the page reloads and all the products are displayed. If I click add to cart again, for the same item, the page reloads, but none of the items show up after it finishes loading. When looking at the page source it shows the block of code where the while loop is meant to be completely blank. everything else in the page loads just that section